# Has anybody experience with the Mac App Store acceptance rules when customising an AppKit behaviour in an unsupported way?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my Objective-C macOS Application, I have found a way to change the font of the windows titles, with this code inserted into my `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController`:

```c
- (void)viewWillLayout {

    NSView *superView = [[[self.view superview] superview] superview];

    for (id view in superView.subviews) {

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]) {

            NSTextField *titleLabel = view;
            NSString *title = titleLabel.stringValue;

            NSFont *font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

            NSAttributedString *smallTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];

            titleLabel.attributedStringValue = smallTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

This works very well. Do you think that Apple could find this unacceptable because it falls into the forbidden private APIs ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your app will be approved, but I wouldn't do it because the view hierarchy is undocumented and can change with even a minor update of iOS. Furthermore the layout in the `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` is not guaranteed to be fixed, so any such future changes might cause strange clippings and other artifacts since your font differs from the original font.

Comment: He is targeting macOS, not iOS. ;) However, the same principle applies. Considering rejection or not, it depends how small the OP wants the window titles to be.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this at all. Apple has not exported this API for a good reason: it wants us developers to use a consistent look to keep the appearance of the OS familiar to the users. You should read Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/) to understand why this is important. It is thus very likely your app will be rejected, because of this hack, unless you have a very good reason to do this.